# Moving to rbenv breaks passenger (nginx)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, rbenv

I moved from RVM to rbenv on my production server. I uninstalled rvm using "rvm implode" and installed rbenv, ruby 1.9.2 , rails, passenger and nginx-module.
I have not modified my originlal nginx.conf apart from changing the passenger_root as follows:

```
1st Try:
passenger_root /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.9;
passenger_ruby /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby;
2nd Try:
passenger_root /root/.rbenv/shims/passenger;
passenger_ruby /root/.rbenv/shims/ruby;
```

Now, when I try to run my application I see the following error in error.log:

```
[error] 1291#0: *105 open() "/home/passenger/grabber/current/public/view" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

This clearly indicates that passenger has not launched and my rails app is not recognized. When I try to manually start passenger, I get the following error:

```
   [ pid=17605 thr=70022120 file=utils.rb:176 time=2011-10-23 23:40:41.917 ]: *** Exception LoadError in PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner (libruby.so.1.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/passenger/grabber/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so) (process 17605, thread #<Thread:0x858e7d0>):
from /home/passenger/grabber/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
```

I have installed nokogiri several times and I can see nokogiri in my gem list. I am not sure why moving to to rbenv has broken passenger for me.

Comment: Anyways, I removed rbenv and moved back to RVM. Good riddance.

Answer (score -15, accepted):

There seems to be no compatibility between passenger and rbenv (make sure you know this before you shoot yourself in the foot) - so I removed rbenv and moved back to RVM...

Comment: False assertion. passenger and rbenv works juste fine.

Answer (score 21):

It is possible to use rbenv, nginx and passenger. Some have gone for a system-wide install. http://blakewilliams.me/blog/4-system-wide-rbenv-install

I'm currently testing on my development environment so, assuming you have installed rbenv and have the correct rbenv init in your `.bashrc`:

```
gem install passenger
rbenv rehash
sudo bash -c "source ~/.bashrc && passenger-install-nginx-module"
```

You must `gem install passenger` to get the shims. Doing `bundle install` to install passenger won't give you these.

Finally:

```
passenger-config --root
```

will give you your `passenger_root` path and:

```
rbenv which ruby
```

your `passenger_ruby` path.

The passenger shim points to the executable but `passenger_root` must be a path to the folder. I've tried using the ruby shim but it doesn't work. I've not dug into why yet.

BTW, I do have the nokogiri gem in my Gemfile. Oh, also if you have `.rvmrc` and/or `config/setup_load_paths.rb` it should be safe to remove these as passenger autoloads bundler.

I still need to do a bit more testing on this but so far so good.

Comment: I've changed the link to a recent blog post but I've not confirmed it works. If anyone confirms, let me know.

Comment: "Support" for rbenv seems like it would support the actual functionality of rbenv, which is to have different ruby binaries for each Ruby application, and use each applications' configuration to select it. You have to manually bypass rbenv and configure Passenger with a specific Ruby binary, and you can only specify one ruby binary for all of Passenger. @Ved is essentially correct, it's not supported. But neither is rvm.