# Cannot find nginx.conf using passenger-nginx and rbenv

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, nginx, passenger, rbenv

I recently created a Linode server with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

as the admin user aurelien I installed rbenv (in my case 1.9.3-p194 for my older rails 3.2 app).

Afterwhich I ran `gem install passenger` and was placed in the directory `~/.rbenv/shims`

After that I ran `rbenv rehash`

and to install nginx:

I couldn't run `passenger-install-nginx-module` because it asked to use with `sudo`. When I tried `sudo passenger-install-nginx-module` it told me `command not found`.

Then I found this post [PhilT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868090/moving-to-rbenv-breaks-passenger-nginx)

and tried running `sudo bash -c "source ~/.bashrc && passenger-install-nginx-module"`

```
/home/aurelien/.rbenv/shims/passenger-install-nginx-module
```

I went through the entire passenger/nginx installation and pressed "enter" when it asked for the prefix directory.

in my root directory `cd ~/home/aurelien` and I can't find `/opt/nginx`.

Did it correctly create these directories?

The only directories/files I have on the root are these:

```
.  ..  apps  .bash_history  .bash_logout  .bashrc  .cache  .gem  .gitconfig  .profile  .rbenv  .ssh  .viminfo
```

EDIT: My .bashrc file

```
export RBENV_ROOT="${HOME}/.rbenv"

if [ -d "${RBENV_ROOT}" ]; then
  export PATH="${RBENV_ROOT}/bin:${PATH}"
  eval "$(rbenv init -)"
fi


# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

Comment: it's a bit hard to debug where you went wrong without some more info.. but hope this article might help: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu

Comment: Thank you Jay for your answer, but in my case I am not using RVM. Is there any way to debug? Should I just create the directories myself /opt/nginx ?

Comment: my guess: you installed passenger in your rbenv user, but then you try a command dependent on that passenger through sudo (the root), which does not have passenger installed. I would suggest: 1. use rvm or 2. gem install passenger on the root user? (sudo gem install passenger). not sure about more than that without more direct knowledge..

Comment: ...wait did you write rbenv into your .bashrc file?

Comment: as outlined in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868090/moving-to-rbenv-breaks-passenger-nginx?lq=1 maybe you ran the ``sudo bash -c..`` command before adding rbenv into bashrc

Comment: No I added rbenv in bashrc right after I installed rbenv as noted in the instructions. But maybe it is a root problem. Thing is: How do I install passenger-install-nginx-module without sudo? It will tell me I have a permission issue. Also in the Passenger User Guide, they do mention I can make an install for user instead of root. I would like to avoid RVM, I tried before and wasted 2 days on RVM.

Comment: It's not possible to install nginx without root access for most servers (it is a system-wide install). Your other option could be to try giving your ubuntu user root access, but this is typically considered poor for security purposes.

Comment: (that's not to say that you can't install passenger as a non-root user.. just nginx typically requires that kind of access).

Comment: Then should I `gem uninstall passenger`. Then `ssh root@my_ip`, as root `gem install passenger` followed by `passenger-install-nginx-module`? My Ruby is installed under `/home/aurelien/.rbenv/shims/ruby`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47483/discussion-between-aurelien-schlumberger-and-jay)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer posted before by PhilT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868090/moving-to-rbenv-breaks-passenger-nginx) had the correct code for installing nginx together with passenger:

> gem install passenger
>   rbenv rehash
>   sudo bash -c "source ~/.bashrc && passenger-install-nginx-module"

The fault in your explanation above is that /opt/nginx is not in user's home directory (~/home/aurelien/opt/nginx), but in the root directory (plainly /opt/nginx.), as nginx is a system-wide install.

(Note: In some other systems nginx also has config files placed in /etc/nginx instead)