# Nginx Passenger won't start due to these lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, nginx, passenger

My Passenger/Nginx configuration won't start and it must be due to these two lines:

```
passenger_root /usr/bin/passenger;
passenger_ruby /usr/local/rbenv/shims/ruby;
```

When I run `which passenger`, I get /usr/bin/passenger but not sure if thats correct?

Anyone have more knowledge about this?

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868090/moving-to-rbenv-breaks-passenger-nginx?rq=1

Comment: @rctneil, what's do you get if you run "passenger-config --root" ?

Comment: I get this: `/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini`

Comment: @rctneil that weird, it should point out to the passenger gem location. In my production server it gives something like /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/passenger-4.0.23

Answer (score 0):

`passenger_root` can be looked up by:

`$ passenger-config --root
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini`

`passenger_ruby` can be determined by rbenv:

`$ rbenv which ruby 
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/ruby`